# Inconsistent font styling in 'less-than-15-reputation' .message alert

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message

This is a rather nit-picky styling gripe, but one that nevertheless bears mentioning:

Earlier I was attempting to comment on a helpful answer I read on Stack Overflow, but, alas, I was prompted I could not do so what for my lack of sufficient Reputation.

I noticed, however, that the font styling of this `.message` prompt in question was inconsistent with that of other similarly-classed prompts that can be triggered. 
Observe:

[image: Arial]

versus:

[image: Helvetica]

I did my best to inspect and see where this particular instance of `.message` loses the inherited `font-family` property `"Helvetica Neue"` and falls back on `Serif`, but I didn't have any luck.

Perhaps someone with a little more CSS know-how could shed some light on this problem?